# After Effects CS6 Problem

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, compositing, aerender

I try to render with After Effects CS6. I have a weird problem. Here render result:

Sometimes, it's show some old frames as you see in video.

Here normal video (rendered with Camtasia):

My AE render settings are default. And this is being every (fresh&new) project. Would you have a suggestion for this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Camtasia 8's capture. Converting from the AVI format to a MOV format fixed the issue.